# Why inline script > External stylesheet is faster than External stylesheet > Script?

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance

[1. stylesheet > Script](http://stevesouders.com/cuzillion/?c0=hc1hfff2_0_f&c1=hc1hfff2_0_f&c2=hb0wfff0_0_f&c3=hb0wfff0_0_f&c4=bi1hfff2_0_f&c5=bi1hfff2_0_f&t=1438003196394)

http://stevesouders.com/cuzillion/?c0=hc1hfff2_0_f&c1=hc1hfff2_0_f&c2=hb0wfff0_0_f&c3=hb0wfff0_0_f&c4=bi1hfff2_0_f&c5=bi1hfff2_0_f&t=1438003196394

[2. Script > stylesheet](http://stevesouders.com/cuzillion/?c0=hb0wfff0_0_f&c1=hb0wfff0_0_f&c2=hc1hfff2_0_f&c3=hc1hfff2_0_f&c4=bi1hfff2_0_f&c5=bi1hfff2_0_f&t=1438003184842)

http://stevesouders.com/cuzillion/?c0=hb0wfff0_0_f&c1=hb0wfff0_0_f&c2=hc1hfff2_0_f&c3=hc1hfff2_0_f&c4=bi1hfff2_0_f&c5=bi1hfff2_0_f&t=1438003184842

My understanding was scripts block the parsing. So having script before stylesheet will slow down the page load. However in the above instance when I have inline script before the CSS files the page load faster?

Can someone explain why?

Comment: depends on the scripts, I guess (no way I'm following blind links with 1000 characters in them

Comment: @JaromandaX lol fair enough here is the site... that was the direct link to the test I've created http://stevesouders.com/cuzillion/

Comment: By faster you mean why sometime one takes 30ms more than the other ? I got random results and there is no faster one.

Comment: @Hacketo yes roughly speak... its not much difference but I assume when you have more content etc difference would be greater?

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the difference on two events 'DomContentLoaded' and 'Load'

Difference between Load event in the two case is approx 5-15ms ( Second one is faster )
But Difference between DomContentLoaded is 2.5s ( Second one is faster ). I am not sure,  Reason behind this should be script is parsed before the css starts downloading from the network.